# C++ class with public:ctor(), what does it mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I just stumbled upon this piece of code:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:MyClass();
        void             DoMagic();

    private:
        void             DoRealMagic();

    private:
        int              m_iSomething;
};
```

I wonder about this line:

```
public:MyClass();
```

What exactly does it mean and do?! I have never seen this before in C++ ... seems like it has something to do with the default ctor?!

Comment: If a user-defined ctor isn't public, it can't be used to construct an object from the outside world.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I know, I just totally missed, that this code is valid even WITHOUT a line break ... that confused me a little bit. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write as well

```
 public:
      MyClass();
```

to make it clearer.

It's just a public default constructor declaration. No magic, nothing special.

> I have never seen this before in C++ ...

Yes, it's very unusual to write it as seen. Proper line breaks and indentations are making the code much clearer to read.

Comment: @DoubleVoid Of course, line breaks are great to de-obfuscate code ;-P.